# Prove $\int_{1/6}^1 \frac{\arccos x}{(1+2x)\sqrt{1+x}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+3x}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\right)dx=\frac{2}{15}\pi^2.$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

\begin{align*}
I:&=\int_{1/6}^1 \frac{\arccos x}{(1+2x)\sqrt{1+x}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+3x}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\right)dx\\
&=\int_{1/6}^1 \frac{\arccos x}{(1+2x)\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1+3x}}dx+\int_{1/6}^1 \frac{2\arccos x}{(1+2x)\sqrt{x+x^2}}dx.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
J:&=\int_{1/6}^1 \frac{\arccos x}{(1+2x)\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1+3x}}dx\\
&=\int_{1/6}^1 \frac{\arccos x}{(1+2x)\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1+3x}}dx\\
&=\int_{1/6}^1 \arccos x d\left(2\arctan \sqrt{\frac{3x+1}{x+1}}\right)\\
&=\left[2\arccos x \arctan \sqrt{\frac{3x+1}{x+1}}\right]_{1/6}^1+2\int_{1/6}^1 \arctan \sqrt{\frac{3x+1}{x+1}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx.
\end{align*}
The latter item resembles **Ahmed's integral**, but how to go on with this?